# AWS S3 url with CNAME compliant virtual name

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3, cname

I'm trying to create a cname to my us-east-1 s3 bucket, something like this:

```
media.domain.com => media.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com
```

I followed the guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs) to create a bucket with a dns compliant name.

However, instead of the URL being something like media.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com, it instead is the following which I can't use for cname redirection because of the slash:

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.domain.com/
```

I looked here at the s3 path deprecation plan, and I would assume that us-east-1 would get [this first](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)

However, when I try to access the domain through paths recommended [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html)

The SSL breaks

I've tried the following:

- `media.domain.com.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
- `media.domain.com.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com (notice the dash between s3 and us)`
- `media.domain.com.s3-control.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`
- `media.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

> When using virtual hosted–style buckets with SSL, **the SSL wild-card
> certificate only matches buckets that do not contain dots (".")**. To
> work around this, use HTTP or write your own certificate verification
> logic

[amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan-the-rest-of-the-story/)

You need to rename the bucket that does not contain `dots (".")` or use path style URL avoided SSL error.

As it should work for

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/media.domain.com/
```

But the SSL will break for `media.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com`

or you can CloudFront that is suggested by @Chris or you can look into another easy option [VirtualHostingCustomURLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html#VirtualHostingCustomURLs)

To use custom SSL with S3.

- Create cloudfront distribution
- Add SSL under **SSL Certificate**
- Sepcify  Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs)  for example media.domain.com
- Create origin Group and specify S3 bucket
- Add route 53 record to point to cloudfront distrubtion
- Awsome you can now access `https://media.domain.com/object.jpg`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just saw that for the Virtual Hosting Custom URLs (which I linked to in my post) doesn't support SSL: _Virtual hosted URLs are supported for non-SSL (HTTP) requests only_

Comment: okay. Answer updated to work with Cluodfront with custom domain and custom SSL.

Answer (score 2):

The `media.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com` CNAME for HTTPS on your custom domain will fail any SSL verification as the certificate is for `s3.amazonaws.com` subdomains not `media.domain.com` subdomains.

In addition by trying to access `media.domain.com.s3.amazonaws.com` directly in the browser it will fail SSL verification at the SSL is only valid for a single level subdomain (`*.s3.amazonaws.com`).

If you want to get around this you will need to host this domain to resolve to a [CloudFront distribution](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) that [sits in front of your S3 bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/).

By doing this you can specify the SSL when you create the distribution that it should use.

Comment: I totally didn't see this little addendum: _Virtual hosted URLs are supported for non-SSL (HTTP) requests only._

Comment: Yes its a limitation primarily because of the SSL. Most people would use CloudFront for this to use their own subdomain :)

Answer (score 0):

[2023]
No such problem for now
Here is the method I use:

1-
Adding a CNAME record to a domain on Cloudflare

2-
Creating a Bucket with the subdomain and domain name to be used on AWS S3 (for example "static.domain.com") and making it Public.

3-
The bucket url on AWS S3 now looks like this
"https://s3.eu-central-2.amazonaws.com/static.domain.com"
but you are in the CNAME record
"static.domain.com.s3.eu-central-2.amazonaws.com"
you should add as

4-
[Most Important Step] => WAIT,
As soon as you make the above settings, do not expect an immediate result, you will get an ssl error.
So wait at least 1 hour and see the result.

Good luck.

Comment: The question is not about how to create a CNAME but why the created CNAME does not work with SSL.